# How to set model field automatically in CreateView? (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
class PetAddView(CreateView):
    model = Pet
    fields = ['name','animal_type','breed','color','age','height','price','city','sex','photo']
    template_name = 'pets/pet-add.html'
```

There's my create view.

My goal is to provide view with functionality to create record in database. Bu I don't need my users to specify slug instead I need to set it automatically from specified "name" value.

Can I?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do absolutely anything in the `form_valid` method. The trick is

```
def form_valid( self, form):

    instance = form.save( commit = False)
    # define the slug and any other programmatically generated fields
    instance.slug = whatever
    instance.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect( self.get_success_url())
```